# Checking input value > 0 jQuery coffee

Tags: jquery, if-statement, coffeescript

I want to do a simple check that an input field on one of my forms has text entered and if it does move the progress indicator towards 16 if it doesnt do nothing.

Clearly I'm missing something simple here but shouldn't I just be able to check that the val is greater than 1 here?

Here is the coffee-

```
jQuery ->
    $("#user_first_name").blur (event) ->
      if $(this).val > 1
        setInterval (->
            front_index_gage.refresh 16
            ), 500
      else
```

Is this an error in my coffee syntax?

=======UPDATE=============

After ensuring that the first field check worked it seems that this isnt the most elegant solution as this is the path I would be going down

```
jQuery ->
    $("#user_first_name").blur (event) ->
      if $(this).val().length > 1
        setInterval (->
            front_index_gage.refresh 16
            ), 500
      else
jQuery ->
    $("#user_last_name").blur (event) ->
      if $(this).val().length > 1
        setInterval (->
            front_index_gage.refresh 33
            ), 500
      else
        setInterval (->
            front_index_gage.refresh 16
            ), 500
```

with 6 form fields to check fairly new to js and coffee but is this a case where I would use a switch conditional to check and refresh the progress indicator?

Thanks again for your attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"has text entered" means "there is one character or more in the value ", i.e. "the *length* is > 0". You're comparing the value itself.

Comment: This helped me arrive to the correct answer as I had the parens on previously but wasn't able to get the desired result. I appended a '.length' with the added parens and everything is working as it should.

Answer (score 3):

You need parentheses for the `.val()` function which you don't want to pass any parameters to.

Like this should work.

```
if $(this).val() > 1
```

Otherwise `.val` is trying to use `> 1` as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your attention I had tried this previously but it wasn't working for me. It was your answer combined with @pimvdb that helped me arrive at the correct solution. I needed the () but I also need to add .length to answer the question in the way I was asking it. Thanks :)

Comment: Not quite. `o.p > 1` is interpreted exactly the same as it is in JavaScript so `$(this).val > 1` is trying to compare the `val` function with the number `1`.

Answer (score 1):

`.val` it's a function, so you should fix this:

```
if $(this).val() > 1
```